# Does NSSelectorFromString(@"methodName"); create an object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So far, I've learned these ways to create objects in Obj-C:

```
[[FooClass alloc] init]  
[FooClass new]  
[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
```

Now I've come across:

```
SEL aSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"methodName");
```

and that syntax confuses me.
Is *aSelector* an instance of the class SEL, making *NSSelectorFromString* a factory method that does not follow Obj-C syntax?

note: As per Apple documentation:
"Compiled selectors are of **type** SEL."
"You use a selector **created** from a string when you want your code to send a message whose name you may not know until runtime."

Comment: It is not an object. Might be closer to a struct internally.

Comment: My impression is that a selector is a structure, not a full-blown object.  Any literal selector (`numberWithInt:`, eg) is compiled in to your code as a sequence of bytes in the program's constant data segment.  Where you declare a `SEL` I *think* that's handled as a plain old C data structure -- the entire structure is allocated in the `aSelector` variable location, not in some separate "object".

Comment: `SEL` is not a class, it's a simple C struct.

Comment: SEL is not a class, its a struct. is defined as `typedef struct objc_selector *SEL;`

SEL is a type used to store a selector, which basically is the "name" of a method, along with some other information.

Comment: @gabuh Is it fair to say a class name will never have every letter capitalized? So, I should been able to see right away that "aSelector" was not an object.

Comment: @user312440, well, you could create a class with every letter capitalized. It's just a convention not to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSSelectorFromString()` is a function, whereas your first 3 examples are methods. That is simply the syntax for a function. It is called on its own and not by any particular object.

As far as selectors:

As per the documentation:

> SEL
>
> Defines an opaque type that represents a method selector.
>
> typedef struct objc_selector *SEL;
>
> Discussion Method selectors are used to represent the name of a method
>   at runtime. A method selector is a C string that has been registered
>   (or “mapped“) with the Objective-C runtime. Selectors generated by the
>   compiler are automatically mapped by the runtime when the class is
>   loaded.

It's a struct, not a class.

Comment: I had thought that a coding convention is to never begin a function name with a capital letter?

Comment: In general yes, but in the case of functions and in particular, the ones in [Apple frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html), they are typically namespaced. As you can see, all foundation functions are prefixed with `NS`.

Comment: @user312440 Never begin a *method name* with a capital letter.  Functions are almost always started with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

`SEL` is not an Objective-C class. It's a typedef'd name for a private `struct`:

```
/// An opaque type that represents a method selector.
typedef struct objc_selector *SEL;
```

Selectors are created and owned by the runtime library itself; `NSSelectorFromString()` might cause the selector to be created, but it's more likely that it's just being *retrieved* from an existing list.

Answer (score 0):

look at the SEL structure

> typedef struct objc_selector *SEL;

its used to represent the name of the method. `SEL` type in objective-c is a pointer to struct objc_selector

> NSSelectorFromString ,

it return the SEL from string.

[SEL Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SEL)